# Как вывести сообщение в окно чата?

Tags: php

У меня есть чат и iframe. В базу сообщение заносит, но как вывести через цикл не работает.

Вот чат:

```
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="1265" height="400"></iframe>   
<form action="iframe.php" method="post" name="form" target='chatWindow' >
<p>Сообщение:<input name="message" type="text" size="75" maxleght="255">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK">
</p>
<br>
```

И iframe:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
$message = $_POST ['message'];
}

$db = mysql_connect("sql-4.zerver.ru","**","**");
mysql_select_db("**",$db);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('$message')");
?>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ)))) РАБОТАЕТ)))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я могу судить, у вас чат сделан с постоянной перезагрузкой ифрейма. Если так, то после того, как вы заносите сообщение в базу, вам надо просто выбрать из нее последние, сколько надо или все (это как сами решаете) и вывести их на экран пользователю.
Если же у вас ифрейм - это не поле, где выписываются сообщения, значит, вам нужно делать еще обращения к скрипту, который будет проверять, сколько у вас на экране (какое последнее - лучше для этого использовать переменную в сессии содержащую ИД последнего) и смотреть, сколько после него в базе еще есть и отсылать их пользователю. Само собой все через аякс.

Comment: Первый вариант правильный)) Но как вывести сообщение в iframe?

Comment: первый тоесть каждый раз перезагрузка ифрейма и в нем сообщения выписываются. ну тогда просто вытащите их туда допустим все. <pre>
$db = mysql_connect("sql-4.zerver.ru","**","**");
mysql_select_db("**",$db);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('$message')");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){

echo "{$row['message']}<br>";
}
</pre>
это если все выводить.